# If current row and column cell not blank then next row

Tags: excel, vba

1st post. I have an excel workbook and I cannot figure out how to code if a row is active and column F has a value(Date) in it then the next available row and columns get populated. I have looked up If Range, IsError, If Goto, I am just not sure where to place in current code. Nothing I have found online seems to work or I am just not using the correct syntax.

```
With ws
    irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value = Application.Index(Range("C2:C500"), Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, Range("B2:B500"), 0))
    ws.Cells(irow, 2).Value = Application.Index(Range("D2:D500"), Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, Range("B2:B500"), 0))
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
n = Application.CountIf(ws.Columns(1), ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value)
If n = 0 Then
    nr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 0
    If nr = 2 And ws.Range("A2") = vbEmpty Then
        nr = 1
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & nr) = ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value
    ws.Range("B" & nr) = ws.Cells(irow, 2).Value
    ws.Range("E" & nr) = Now()
    ws.Range("E" & nr).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

ElseIf n > 0 Then
    nr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 0
    If ws.Cells(nr, 5).Value = ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value Then
        nc = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        ws.Cells(5, nc) = Now()
        ws.Cells(5, nc).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

    Else
        Set bcr = ws.Columns(1).Find(ws.Cells(irow, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        nc = ws.Cells(bcr.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        ws.Cells(bcr.Row, nc) = Now()
        ws.Cells(bcr.Row, nc).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: (a) Why do you test for `n = 0` - `n` appears to be a count of how many times a value from column A exists in column A.  That would surely have to be once, or more.  Am I missing something?  (b) What do you mean by "a row is active" - do you mean that the row has a non-empty cell in **any** of its columns, or do you simply mean that column F (or column A?) is non-empty?

Comment: (c) You have a `With ws` block but never make use of it - did you mean to say `.Range("C2:C500")` (etc) instead of `Range("C2:C500")` (etc)?  If not, which is the ActiveSheet when the code runs - is it the same sheet as referred to by `ws`?

Comment: a, I found code sample and modified it to work. Probably don't need it.

Comment: b. active row simply means the row on sheet4 that I am trying to populate with checked out and in times. c. ws  is referring to sheet 4. I can  copy the rest of code. I only took a snippet of the code from sheet 3  which is the active sheet.

Comment: Looking at your code: (1) You determine the last used row in `ws` and update column A & B of that row to something from the ActiveSheet (2) The `n=0` code doesn't get executed as far as I can see (3) You determine the last row with value in column A (so `nr` is probably the same as `irow`) (4) You compare column E's value with column A's value and, if they are the same, you update some stuff on row 5 (5) If column E was not the same as column A, you find the first occurrence, within column A, of the last row's column A value and add a new column to the end of that row showing the date. ...

Comment: Which of those operations do you need to push to the next row if column F already has a date in it?

Comment: 1. Yes, I find RFID scanned value in column A of sheet 3 and using that sheets table I pull column C (ID) and column D (description). 2. I will comment out to see if it has no effect. 3. Seems to work for the report I am populating, I'm sure there is a better way to find next row available. 4. Not necessary to compare column values, just need to add checked out timestamp when column A and B next row is populated with  sheet 2 table data. Again, code seems to work but could be better.

Comment: 5. What I am actually trying to accomplish is via userform1, someone pushes command button (ScanAssociateID) and then userform1 is hidden and sheet 2 is active. Using find, ID is scanned into cell A1 and with table columns C and D get populated to sheet 4 (report). A time stamp (Now) goes into corresponding row column E (checked cut). userform1 is then shown.

Comment: If the same ID is scanned again, needs to find if row, column F (checked in) has value (Now) in it. If not then fill with (Now) if column F does have value (Now) in it then that row in the report is essentially closed out and a new row should be started.

Comment: 6. It sound like this code is doing something similar to what I need but has some serious flaws. I apologize for the misunderstanding. This is my first project and I have found its and bits of code through searches etc... and muddled through this to try and accomplish this workbook userform. The majority of my userform is functioning as expected but this report sure is proving to be difficult. I want to thank you for taking the time to walk through this with me.